# prolog general rule for finding cousins etc

Tags: prolog

The question is to write a general rule to find any level of relative!

```
cousin(N,Child1,Child2).
```

So that it is true if Child1 and Child2 are Nth cousins. So
cousin1(Child1,Child2) = cousin(1,Child1,Child2) and
cousin2(Child1,Child2) = cousin(2,Child1,Child2) and so on
for third and fourth and even higher level cousins.

What I have so far:

```
/* first person is parent of second person */
parent(a, b).
parent(b, f).
parent(a, d).
parent(f, g).
parent(a, k).
parent(f, h).
parent(k, l).
parent(f, i).
parent(k, m).
parent(l, t).
parent(b, e).

sibling(X,Y) :- parent(Z,X), parent(Z,Y), not(X=Y).

grandparent(X, Z) :-
    parent(X, Y),
    parent(Y, Z).

greatgrandparent(X, Z) :-
    parent(X, Y),
    parent(Y, P),
    parent(P, Z).

cousin1(Child1,Child2) :-
    parent(Y1,Child1),
    parent(Y2,Child2),
    sibling(Y1,Y2).

cousin2(Child1,Child2) :-
    greatgrandparent(Z, Child1),
    greatgrandparent(Z, Child2),
    \+sibling(Child1, Child2),
    \+cousin1(Child1, Child2),
    Child1 \= Child2.
```

This returns false regardless of values input, so clearly I have no idea what I am doing PLEASE help!

```
cousin(N,Child1,Child2) :-
    nth0(N, parent(Y1,Child1),Y1),
    nth0(N, parent(Y2,Child2),Y2),
    cousin1(Y1,Y2).
```

Comment: Two person are cousins or level zero if they are siblings. They are cousins of level N if their parents are cousins of level N-1.

Comment: How do I implement the N part of the coding?

Comment: look for similar examples, by example, "nth element in a list".

Comment: Not finding anything that resembles my specific requirements, but considering I don't really know what I'm looking for, it might be a case of not seeing the forest for the trees!

Comment: How do I access the parent list using nth0(N, ?,?), ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried:

```
    % first person is parent of second person
    parent(a, b).
    parent(b, f).
    parent(a, d).
    parent(f, g).
    parent(a, k).
    parent(f, h).
    parent(k, l).
    parent(f, i).
    parent(k, m).
    parent(l, t).
    parent(b, e).

    sibling(Sib1,Sib2) :- parent(SomeParent,Sib1), 
             parent(SomeParent,Sib2), 
             \+ Sib1 = Sib2.

    % first person is ancestor of second person
    ancestor(Older,Younger,L) :-
             parent(Older,Younger),
             L is 1.
    ancestor(Older,Younger,Level) :- 
             parent(Older,Child),
             ancestor(Child,Younger,L),
             Level is L + 1. 


    %nth_cousin(Level,Cous1,Cous2) :- 
    %             ancestor(Sib1,Cous1,Level),
    %             ancestor(Sib2,Cous2,Level), 
    %             sibling(Sib1,Sib2).  

    nth_cousin(Level,Cous1,Cous2) :- 
             setof((Cous1,Cous2), Sib1^Sib2^(ancestor(Sib1,Cous1,Level), 
                                             ancestor(Sib2,Cous2,Level), 
                                             sibling(Sib1,Sib2)
                                            ), 
                   Cousins),
             member((Cous1,Cous2), Cousins),
             \+ (Cous2@<Cous1, member((Cous2,Cous1), Cousins)).
```

Ex.

```
    1 ?- nth_cousin(1,Cous1,Cous2).
    Cous1 = e,
    Cous2 = l ;
    Cous1 = e,
    Cous2 = m ;
    Cous1 = f,
    Cous2 = l ;
    Cous1 = f,
    Cous2 = m ;
    false.

    2 ?- nth_cousin(2,Cous1,Cous2).
    Cous1 = g,
    Cous2 = t ;
    Cous1 = h,
    Cous2 = t ;
    Cous1 = i,
    Cous2 = t ;
    false.
```